# QT4 making a dial control semi-transparent over an image

Tags: image, qt4, qwidget, alpha-transparency

I have a dial control over an image

```
scene->addPixmap(*pixmap);
this->ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

and I want to see the underlying image also in the control area. I tried for example

```
this->ui->dial->setStyleSheet("QWidget{background-color: rgba(0,250, 0,40%);}");
```

but the control is opaque, I cannot see the image beneath, whatever % I set for the alpha channel. Which are the right instructions?

Comment: What's the base class of your dial?

Comment: @Phlucious it' a common dial from the QT controls palette, so I think it's the QDial class.